# How to use the word "on"

Tags: prepositions

Is the statement "Jennifer is on the front row." grammatically correct? I was told that this statement is incorrect because Jennifer cannot get on top of the row but she can get in the row.  Please clarify which is correct to use in the sample sentence above.

Comment: I'd direct you to choster's answer and my comment there.

Comment: **In** *the front row*; if the row contains seats and Jennifer is sitting on one.

Answer (score 3):

If you are giving Jennifer's location in an audience, she is *in* the front row, in the basic sense of *in* referring to a position within something. She may be standing in the row, and *in* it because she is occupying the space within the seats and those seats in front; she may be sitting in the row, and *in* it because the seat is somewhere in the sequence of seats in the row.

When referring to position or location, *on* usually indicates resting on an outer or upper surface, or proximity to a point on a line or border, neither of which is applicable to a front row of seats. But *on* would be applicable in a number of other narrow scenarios, as it has many uses other than the primary location-related meanings.

For example, *on* can be *a function word to indicate the focus of obligation or responsibility* ([Merriam-Webster definition 7c](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on)). Perhaps one is describing work  assignments:

> The security staff take these positions during intermission: Jan and Rick are on toilet lines, Christina is on fire exits, Oscar is on cashbox, and Jennifer is on the front row.

Another use is *to indicate destination or the focus of some action, movement, or directed effort* (MW 9a). Perhaps one is going through an auditorium sequentially:

> In advance of the speech, bomb squads are sweeping the house. The mezzanine is completed, and in the loge, Thomas is on row 23, but in the orchestra, Jennifer is on the front row still.

Answer (score 3):

**It depends on how you think of the row**

The answer depends on how you are thinking of the row, as mentioned by **Araucaria** above.

What is a row? If it is a row of people, you are within the row, you are part of the row, you are thus 'in' the row - e.g. I will be sitting in the 4th row.
If you said 'on' when talking about the row of people, it would suggest you are on top of the people.

If however, you are talking about the actual row of seats, and thinking of the row as a collective single object, then you could in fact be 'on' the row - e.g. I will be sitting on the 4th row.

In my own personal experience, 'in' is used most often in this context. I have never heard someone say they are 'on' a row in the context of a row at a concert or venue.

In response to Edwin Ashworth's claim that Google gives him such a high result when searching for 'on the front row'; a similar search using 'in the front row' will give roughly if not exactly the same amount of results. You have to understand google's method for fetching up results, and based on the two searches giving the same result I'd assume Google is disregarding the 'in' or 'on' preposition as it doesn't help filter the result enough - i.e. it doesn't distinguish it enough, so this can't be used as evidence for or against.

**Further Clarification**

One of the answers above mentioned an example as such 'I am on oxford street' - this is correct because you are standing on the street, you are on top of it.

Also mentioned was 'I am on the metropolitan line'  (an underground subway route in England) - to avoid confusion, the reason why 'on' works in this sentence is because he says he is 'on the line' which is to mean, he is 'in' the carriage, but the carriage is 'on' the line, so he is effectively 'on' the line,

There are also figures of speech to contend with. For example, when on the phone to a friend in London and someone asks you what you are doing, you say 'I am on the line to London', which is not literal but metaphorical. However, one should be able to assume the differences as they're often obviously improbable -i.e. you wouldn't be on top of the phone line (unless you're a tightrope walker).

Comment: o how do you explain the 19,900,000 Google hits for "on the front row"? You're ignoring metaphorical broadening. 'I am in a shop in Oxford Street' is also widely used; does this mean that the speaker is up to his neck in tarmac?

Comment: I think you're missing the point of this website i.e. Just because something is widely used doesn't make it correct grammar.

Comment: That 19,900,000 Google hits for "on the front row" boggled my mind @EdwinAshworth.  I have never heard that myself, here in the US Midwest but just shows that we can always expand our knowledge! :-)

Comment: @Aidan You're missing the point of this website. When something is widely used, that process almost always redefines correct usage. Prepositional usage becomes idiosyncratic and often unpredictable – perhaps even inexplicable – when non-prototypical usages are considered. Do you say 'I am in the train to Denver'? It would be the logical choice. This has all been addressed before on ELU. Perhaps you ought to read before you write.

Comment: I'm not, but again, I think you've missed the point of the website. Of course we understand that language changes with usage, but we are answering you based on what the current correct usage is. How do you define when the "something" you mentioned has been used enough times to now be the 'norm' or acceptable? If you already think that widespread usage is the test of it being acceptable, then your google search should have given you the answer you wanted and you didn't need to ask the question.

Comment: Further to that, factor in all the non-native english speaking google searches and you might have an answer to your conundrum.

Comment: I've been accustomed to hearing of someone 'being on the nth row' for over 50 years. It might not be as common as 'being in the nth row', but 'on the nth row' is certainly not (as you claim) unacceptable. It's an example of what what Bennett (1975) in his localistic theory of prepositions terms a 'quasi-physical space' usage.  And your judgement of when specific metaphorical usages of prepositions are acceptable is subjective. Not all the 19 900 000 hits for "on the front row" may be relevant, but you've only cited one person who claims that "The answer is 'in' not 'on'" – yourself.

Comment: You may have a technical point, but you just need to look at the responses here (bar your own), and you'll see that most people agree that 'in' is more common, or more widely used.

Comment: I agree that 'in the first row' is more common. _I said so in my previous comment._ **Who** 'just need/s to look'? I'm pointing out that (1) your claim "The answer is 'in' not 'on'" should be "Both are used, with 'in' being a lot more common"; (2) 'Just because something is widely used doesn't make it correct grammar.' cannot be used to substantiate your (or any) claim, and you give no authoritative support for your claim. Have you actually read anything addressing prototypical to peripheral (highly metaphorical) usages of prepositions? Logic is seldom the determining factor here....

Comment: ... You actually mention metaphorical ('not literal') usages that complicate the issue yourself, but don't analyse these particular usages (in/on the front row) accurately, and end up with a subjective and over-prescriptive answer. (3) Araucaria's answer here is well thought out and far more accurate. –  Edwin Ashworth 2 mins ago

Comment: @Kristina Lopez I never understand Google stats. I'm pretty sure I got the figures right last night (Manchester), but I've checked, and it's 103 000 000 hits (many seem recent) now. As compared with 123 000 000 for "in the front row". Perhaps that indicates that 'the "something" ... mentioned has been used enough times to now ... be acceptable', or perhaps Aidan still thinks he should have the final say.

Comment: I'm sure you, as the older gentleman, will be the mature one and let me have the last word :) I agree with Araucaria's answer in that it depends on how you think of the row. I was thinking of the most general, or often, in my mind, usage, which of course is subjective. If you'd like to talk about the algorithms for google search results we'd be here for years.

Comment: It's getting better. But you've come up with another error: 'You have to understand [G]oogle's method for fetching up results, and based on the two searches giving the same result I'd assume Google is disregarding the 'in' or 'on' preposition as it doesn't help filter the result enough.' Adding double inverted commas forces the search to not disregard any of the included words. Thus for "longest word in English", 566 000 hits; "longest word of English", 4500 hits; "longest word at English", 2 hits (well, 1 + 1 repeat). Raw numbers of Google hits _can_ create misleading impressions ...

Comment: ... but offering no substantiating evidence at all is not really what is required on ELU. I'm glad that you've picked up the underlying concept here: this is one of the cases where the choice/s of preposition can be (almost certainly correctly) explained by the (slightly) metaphorical conception of the true situation: **It depends on how you think of the row**. But adjusting one's answer to match the best one is also disallowed on ELU.

Answer (score 1):

'In' would be the correct preposition. One is sitting 'in the front row' because they are one of a row of people. Much like one is 'in line,' 'in formation,' etc. This particular person is 'in' a row that happens to be the first of several.

Comment: So how do you explain the 19,900,000 Google hits for "on the front row"?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the way you think of the row.

If you are thinking of a line of chairs, "in" best conveys the thought.

If you are thinking of a series of rows, then I believe "on" is the right choice.

Comment: [But.. why?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4smXP46tG4)

Answer (score -2):

This is fine (sometimes).

We are interpreting it as:

> "Jennifer is on a seat in the front row"

and we just don't mention the seat because it isn't needed - what else would she sit on?

If, however, you mean:

> "Jennifer is in the front row of a dance"

it is in. On is only for when you are sitting on the front row of a theatre / lecture / cinema.

Comment: That doesn't sound natural to me.  I would think the options are 1) "Jennifer is *in* a seat *in* the front row" - or 2) "Jennifer is sitting on a chair in the front row" but not "Jennifer is on a seat in the front row"

Comment: 'We' certainly doesn't include me.

Comment: 'We' certainly doesn't include me. What do 'we' interpret '[Look at those two butterflies.] The Red Admiral is on the right' as? Is a seat involved here?